# Android Java Sqlite search and replace

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out a way to execute some sort of search and replace in an sqlite column. Say for instance a column has the word "Hello" and it can be in numerous rows and I'd like to replace Hello with "Goodbye" How can I go about this. I know how to update individual rows but cannot seem to find anything about multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using the `update` method as you do when updating individual rows can work:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();             
cv.put(MYCOLUMN, "GoodBye" );
db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, MYCOLUMN + "= ? ", new String[] { "Hello"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a 'normal' SQL statement, like:

```
String updateGreeting = "UPDATE <table> SET <column_name> = 'Goodbye' WHERE <column_name> = 'Hello'";
```

db.execSQL(updateGreeting);